# Find amount of edges and vertices of a plane graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

*A plane graph $G$ has 7 faces: 3 triangles, 3 quadrilaterals and 1 pentagon. How many edges and vertices does it have?*

How this task should be solved? I came up with nothing better, than just manually drawing it and counting edges/vertices. From here, of course, I have no chance to prove that there is no other solution.

[image]

Comment: **Hint:** Every edge belongs to two faces, so count the edges in all the faces and adjust.  Then use Euler's formula to find the number of vertices.

Comment: Is the hint correct? Border edges do not need to belong to 2 faces. However, I'm also missing the pentagon, so my understanding of plane graph may be wrong.

Comment: And for Euler to be unique, the graph has to be connected. Was that given?

Comment: What would your answer be for two triangles? They can be disconnected, share a vertex and share an edge, all giving different answers.

Comment: @Pieter21: The unbounded face (exterior face) counts for the purpose of Euler's formula and should be counted for the sake of having every edge belong to two faces.  The Question claims one pentagon, and in the illustration this pentagon is the unbounded face.  Your concern about uniqueness may be related to various ways of embedding a graph in the plane, but this does not change the number of edges or vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @hardmath [hint in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177516/find-amount-of-edges-and-vertices-of-a-plane-graph?noredirect=1#comment4479167_2177516), the solution is very straightforward:

1. 3 triangles, 3 quadrilaterals and 1 pentagon gives us  26 sides. Each side must be some edge. Each edge must belong precisely to 2 faces. So we have $26/2 = 13$ edges.
2. Using Euler's formula we see that $v + 7 - 13 = 2 \Rightarrow v = 8$